# Problem to install/setup elpy

Tags: elpy

I am trying to install elpy on my machine (ubuntu 14.04), but getting the following issue. any comment, hint?

Thanks.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): elpy in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): importmagic in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from elpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flake8>=2.0 in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from elpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=0.6b1 in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py3.5.egg (from importmagic->elpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyflakes!=1.2.0,!=1.2.1,!=1.2.2,<1.3,>=0.8.1 in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flake8>=2.0->elpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycodestyle<2.1,>=2.0 in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flake8>=2.0->elpy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mccabe<0.6,>=0.2.1 in ./work/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flake8>=2.0->elpy)
```

Comment: As always, please provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Most of us are not mindreaders (though you might luck out by finding one here who recognizes your problem from such a rudimentary description).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it in emacs as well.

`M-x <RET> package-install <RET> elpy <RET>`

Then in your `init.el` add `(elpy-enable)`

Now when you open python files you should see the `elpy` minor mode enabled